# Doing binary search in an array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, structure, binary-search

So i have this structure called jogo and an array with variables of type jogo.

Structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char nome[1024];
    char equipas[2][1024];
    int pont[2];
} jogo;
```

What i want is to do is a binary search to find the corresponding nome and return its id when the nome is found.

Example:

```
// Example of elements inside the array
jogo array[3] = {{0,ElClassico1,Barcelona,RealMadrid,2,0},
                 {1,ElClassico2,Barcelona,RealMadrid,1,3},    
                 {2,ElClassico3,Barcelona,RealMadrid,3,4}}
```

So for example if i do a binary search for the name ElClassico2 i want the binary search to return 1 which is the id of that jogo.

If anyone could tell me how i could do that i would appreciate because im not understanding how it can be done.

Comment: did you search on "c binary search tree" because there are a ton of examples.

Comment: no i did not could u link the post to me pls?

Comment: ok i just checked some but i dont want to make a binary tree, what i want is to do a  binary search

Comment: For binary search in c please go through this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/

Comment: your struct array is sorted by what (`nome`, or `id`) ?

Comment: my array is sorted by id

Comment: your array is sorted by `id` but you want binary search for `nome`. it seems strange. My opinion,  you should sort your array by `nome` before using binary search by `nome`.

Comment: ok ill try it then

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use standard library binary search, you can use it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char nome[1024];
    char equipas[2][1024];
    int pont[2];
} jogo;

int jogo_compare_nome(void const *a, void const *b)
{
    return strcmp(((jogo*)a)->nome, ((jogo*)b)->nome);
}

int main(void)
{
    jogo array[3] = { 
        {0, "ElClassico1", {"Barcelona", "RealMadrid"}, { 2, 0}},
        {1, "ElClassico2", {"Barcelona", "RealMadrid"}, { 1, 3}},
        {2, "ElClassico3", {"Barcelona", "RealMadrid"}, { 3, 4}},
    };
    jogo j1 = { .nome = "ElClassico2" };
    jogo j2 = { .nome = "ElClassico7" };
    jogo* p;

    p = bsearch(&j1, array, 3, sizeof(jogo), jogo_compare_nome);
    if (p) {
        printf("Found id=%i\n", p->id);
    }
    else {
        printf("Not found!\n");
    }

    p = bsearch(&j2, array, 3, sizeof(jogo), jogo_compare_nome);
    if (p) {
        printf("Found id=%i\n", p->id);
    }
    else {
        printf("Not found!\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Anyway, remember that binary search requires sequences sorted on the search key (ok, partitioned by the key, but that's nitpicking). You can use `qsort()` before searching.

By the way, those 1 KB arrays call for dynamic memory allocation (my opinion).

Comment: its because actually im using dynamic memory allocation, but i only showed a few examples to not make it exhaustive for the reader

Comment: @MartimCorreia I meant dynamic memory allocation inside the struct members. That is `nome` would be better being a `char*` instead of a `char[1024]`. Of course it requires a lot more effort to allocate and deallocate the structures. Remember to accept answers if they are ok.